# SVG - how to enlarge font-size where each word is inside <g> tag and each letter is inside <path> tag?

Tags: svg

How to enlarge font-size where each word is inside 'g' tag and each letter is inside 'path' tag ?

I've tried adding transform: scale(1) to each  but there is the positioning problem...

This is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/hr1xpab7/3/

```
<g id="Szczecinecki_3_" style="
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: scale();
">
            <g>
                <path d="M57.3,249.5l0.5,0c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.1c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.5-0.1      c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2c-0.1,0-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.2      c-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.8-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.4      c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.8-0.1c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.8,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.4c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6l-0.5,0c0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.6      c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.7,0.2c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.4c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4c0.1,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.3      c0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,0.9,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.4c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.4      c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.8,0.2c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-0.9-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.5C57.4,250,57.3,249.7,57.3,249.5z"></path>
                <path d="M61,250.8v-0.4l1.9-2.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0h-1.2v-0.4h2.4v0.3l-1.6,1.9l-0.3,0.3c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0h1.4v0.4H61z"></path>
                <path d="M66.1,249.7l0.5,0.1c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.4,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.4c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.4-1.1      c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.8c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7-0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.2c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.7      l-0.5,0.1c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.2c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.6,0.3c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.9      c0,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,0.9c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.2C66,250.1,66,250,66.1,249.7z"></path>
                <path d="M66.7,250.8v-0.4l1.9-2.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0h-1.2v-0.4h2.4v0.3l-1.6,1.9l-0.3,0.3c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0h1.4v0.4H66.7z"></path>
                <path d="M71.9,249.8l0.5,0.1c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.7c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.3c-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1-0.4c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.4-1.1      c0-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.4-1.2c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.4,1-0.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.4c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.4,1.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1h-2.2      c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.8c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5-0.1C71.7,250.2,71.8,250,71.9,249.8z M70.2,249h1.7      c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.3c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2C70.4,248.6,70.3,248.8,70.2,249z"></path>
                <path d="M75,249.7l0.5,0.1c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.4,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.4c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.4-1.1      c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.8c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7-0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.2c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.7      l-0.5,0.1c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.2c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.6,0.3c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.9      c0,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,0.9c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.2C74.9,250.1,75,250,75,249.7z"></path>
                <path d="M75.9,247.3v-0.6h0.5v0.6H75.9z M75.9,250.8v-3h0.5v3H75.9z"></path>
                <path d="M77.2,250.8v-3h0.5v0.4c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.5,0.9-0.5c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4      c0,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.5v1.8h-0.5V249c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2      c-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,0.8v1.6H77.2z"></path>
                <path class="st6" d="M70.3,254.8c0,1.2-1,2.2-2.2,2.2c-1.2,0-2.2-1-2.2-2.2c0-1.2,1-2.2,2.2-2.2      C69.4,252.6,70.3,253.6,70.3,254.8z"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
```

Comment: Why are you drawing text instead of using `<text>`? That would make changing the size very easy by editing the `font-size:` attribute in the `style`.

Comment: ...SO I did ;) Tanks for the answer.